# How to use salsa20 which is on git

Tags: c++, encryption, stream-cipher

I want to use Salsa20 as a part of my assignment. The implementation is available at [everard/Salsa20](https://github.com/everard/Salsa20) GitHub. The problem is I am new to git and programming.

The document says add  `Salsa20.h` and `Salsa20.inl`, so does this mean that I have to add these files in the header of my `*.cpp` file or is there any other way that I could do that?

I tried to add `Salsa20.h` and `Salsa20.inl` in the header of my program (basically just copied those files to my current directory and tried to compile but ended up with errors). There is also `main.cpp` in the source folder of the project, so should I create main.h and add it as headers to my program. I honestly don't know what to do.

I am familiar with `*.h` files but not with `*.inl` files, I tried to read the questions on stackoverflow but it went over my head. I would also appreciate if someone could help me with that too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by stating you platform, compiler and provide the errors you encountered. We can't guess what errors you encountered when you said *"... and tried to compile but ended up with errors"*.

Comment: The problem is I have added Salsa20.inl also as a header in my cpp file. I was getting errors because of that.  Thanks for your edit and comment. Still don't know why should I have .inl file. If you could shed some light on that it would be helpful. Thanks again. @jww

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you only need as the project README says. Add Salsa20.h and Salsa20.inl files to your project. This means that you must copy this files in your working directory and only include the Salsa20.h in to your code as a header. The main file is a example.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked for me, was trying to add Salsa20.inl and it was causing the problem.